# Get Coarse Location Only without extending MapActivity

Tags: android, gps, location, android-service, android-maps-v2

How to get only coarse location without creating or extending MapActivity and send Lattitude and Longitude data to a service in Android ?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How to get only coarse location without creating or extending MapActivity
```

First thing no need `MapAcitvity` for get current location, you just have to use `LoacaionManager`, but you have to use `GoogleMap API`

This is best [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a) for getCurrentLocation.

Answer (score 1):

Using LocationListener you can get Location Updates, from The Location Manager. You need to get Location from GPS PROVIDER, which returns location from gps receiver, and another option you have by NETWORK PROVIDER, which will return location of network, which is tower, wifi point, etc.